# JSX syntax inside custom node_module cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, redux, babeljs, jsx, redux-devtools

I have a PARENT project (UI written using React) that imports its Redux store from an IMPORTED npm package.

`index.js` **PARENT project**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Root from './containers/Root';

import configureStore from 'custom-store';// Importing the custom package

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root store={configureStore()} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

When `custom-store` package is executed as a standalone project. The file `DevTools.js` parses correctly.

But when `custom-store` package is merely a package imported inside `node_modules` of the PARENT project that is being executed, I am seeing this error:

```
./node_modules/custom-store/src/containers/DevTools.js
Module parse failed: /path/to/project/node_modules/custom-store/src/containers/DevTools.js Unexpected token (7:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default createDevTools(
|   <DockMonitor toggleVisibilityKey="ctrl-h"
|                changePositionKey="ctrl-w">
|     <LogMonitor />
```

`configureStore.js` **IMPORTED project**:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import customApi from '../middleware/custom/api'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools' // I would like to use DevTools in the parent project too for debugging purpose

const configureStore = preloadedState => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, customApi, createLogger()),
      DevTools.instrument()
    )
  )

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(rootReducer)
    })
  }

  return store
}

export default configureStore
```

`DevTools.js`  **IMPORTED project**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools'
import LogMonitor from 'redux-devtools-log-monitor'
import DockMonitor from 'redux-devtools-dock-monitor'

export default createDevTools(
  <DockMonitor toggleVisibilityKey="ctrl-h" // Problem parsing this line
               changePositionKey="ctrl-w">
    <LogMonitor />
  </DockMonitor>
)
```

NOTES:

The custom package contains some JSX code used by `redux-devtools` and thus the error **You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.**.

Possible cause may be some missing preset (e.g. `es2015`, `react`) in `.babelrc` that prevents parsing JSX files.

I would like to use the `redux-devtools` in the PARENT project for debugging purpose rather than just deleting the import completely.

Comment: How are you using Babel on this project?

Comment: At the moment I don't have Babel configured for the project, but I suspect that configuring it might help me to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to manually turn the JSX to JS code and avoiding automatic translation completely, this worked inside `DevTools.js`:

```
const logMonitor = React.createElement(LogMonitor, null)
const dockMonitor = React.createElement(DockMonitor, { toggleVisibilityKey: "ctrl-h", changePositionKey: "ctrl-w" }, logMonitor)
export default createDevTools(dockMonitor)
```